# How to do a calculation on a row and column vector to obtain a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I would like to compute the following expression using MATLAB:

```
ans = cos(ω.t + φ)
```

Where:

- ω is a scalar
- t is a [1 x n] matrix
- φ is a [m x 1] matrix

`ans` should be a [m x n] matrix.

Is it possible to use `arrayfun` to compute this expression? Are they any other MATLAB functions to compute this or do I need to compute it line by line in a `for` loop?

Comment: I would really recommend to avoid the name `ans` as a variable (_unless you don't mind if it's overwritten very quickly_)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a job for... [**bsxfun!**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
w=randn;
n=5; m=4;
t=[1:n];
p=[1:m].';
cos(bsxfun(@plus, w*t, p))
```

Result:

```
ans =

   0.180565  -0.206185  -0.562089  -0.833904  -0.980967
  -0.730080  -0.934792  -0.999659  -0.914976  -0.693411
  -0.969493  -0.803956  -0.518147  -0.154823   0.231664
  -0.317559   0.066034   0.439747   0.747674   0.943748
```

Comment: Always plus one for `bsxfun`!

Answer (score 4):

One possible way

```
t = 1:n;
p = (1:m)';
[tm,pm] = meshgrid(t,p);  % Produces matrices by repeating t and p
ans = cos(w*tm+pm);       % ans is m x n
```